# Union path connected disjoint subspaces, $A, B$ and $C$, $X=A\cup B\cup C$ is path connected

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, connectedness

**Problem:**

Let X be a topological space and let $A, B$ and $ C$ be path-connected subspaces of $X$. Show that if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $C \cap B \neq \emptyset$ then the union $A \cup B \cup C$ is *path-connected.*

---

**My idea:**

For a path connected space $P$, any points $p_1$ and $p_2$ can be connected to one another via a path $f: [0,1] \rightarrow P$ such that $f(0)=p_1$ and $f(1)=p_2$. So all $A, B, C$ have this property. Let their corresponding maps be:

---

$f_A: [0,1] \rightarrow A$ : $f(0)=a_1$ and $f(1)=a_2$, $f_B: [0,1] \rightarrow B$ : $f(0)=b_1$ and $f(1)=b_2$ and, finally, for $C$ $f: [0,1] \rightarrow C$ such that $f(0)=c_1$ and $f(1)=c_2$

---

So to prove the union of all these spaces, $X=A \cup B \cup C$, is path-connected, I was wondering if we could define a new map $f: [0,1] \rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$ where $x$ and $y$ are any points in $X$ and the map $f$ is some composition of $f_A, f_B $ and $f_C$. But I have not managed to formulate this in any formal way.

Thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is this one :

Take $p \in A \cap B$ and $ q\in B \cap C$

Let $x,y \in A \cup B \cup C$,

- if $x\in A$ and $y \in A$, by path-connectedness of $A$, there exists a path between $x$ and $y$.
- if $x\in A$ and $y \in B$, by path-connectedness of $A$, there exists a path between $x$ and $p$, and by path-connectedness of $B$, there exists a path between $p$ and $y$. So there exists a path between $x$ and $y$
- if $x\in A$ and $y \in C$, by path-connectedness of $A$, there exists a path between $x$ and $p$, by path-connectedness of $B$, there exists a path between $p$ and $q$, and by path-connectedness of $B$, there exists a path between $q$ and $y$. So there exists a path between $x$ and $y$
- etc.